# How to sennd a broadcast from a background service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a service from where I want to send a broadcast using:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    public BackgroundService() {
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Background service started");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CUSTOM_INTENT");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
```

The service is started from the Main Activity like so:

```
 public void buttonClick(View view) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

However this does not work, it shows this error:

`.BackgroundService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference`

Can anyone point out why? or provide a working example?

Thanks

Comment: Service is not a valid context during constructor. You have to delay your broadcast at least until `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with localBroadcastReceiver like below in service

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.setAction(YOUR_ACTION_STRING)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

and on activity write below code

```
intentFilter.addAction(YOUR_ACTION_STRING);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(yourReceiver, intentFilter)
```

and yourReceiver param extends from broadcastReceiver